# Android ListView with custom item which one field is other custom list of item (not list view need to be not scrollable)

Tags: android, listview, containers, listviewitem

Hi I have list view with custom item adapter: 
My custom item have:
Text View 
Text View 
ListView which have other custom adapter for each item. 
But list view is not best option cause child list view can't be scrolled vertically as parent does. I need replace this listView with other container with custom row view which will be not scrollable as list view but change size with more items.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: replace parent or children list view with ExpandableListView ?

Comment: I am only providing a suggestion which you can google for more information. You have not given enough information for me to do more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ExpandableListView as your "parent" list. There you have to specify groups for your children views. 
For more information, visit this site with an ExpandableListView sample:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/